# How to unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

Tags: mysql

I was trying to connect to a remote mysql server,i was not able to connect to it as a result of which connection through my host IP address is blocked.

This is the exception that i am getting
java.sql.SQLException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Host 'xyz' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

How do i use mysqladmin flush-hosts i am not able to understand.Where do i write it.Is it in the command prompt.Can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a program meant to be run from the command prompt; so SSH (or whatever means you normally do) to the remote server that has MySQL running on it and type the `mysqladmin flush-hosts` command. You may want to first read about what you're going to do with a quick Google search or `man mysqladmin`.

You'll generally need to authenticate, using the standard -u and -p command switches, so something like `mysqladmin -u root -p flush-hosts` is probably what you need (substitute your username for `root` if you have a different, properly authorized user).